# Difference firefox and firefox-from-package-manager

Tags: firefox

I restarted my pc after a long time and after booting up I had two firefox installations on my pc.

```
$> ll /usr/bin/firefox*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jän  8 15:29 /usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Mär 26  2018 /usr/bin/firefox-from-package-manager -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

Both have the same version, but both apparently use different profiles. `firefox-from-package-manager` has all my extensions, history and booksmarks, while `firefox` seem to be backed by a complete new profile.

Also the 'about' dialog of `firefox` has the addition of

```
Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu
canonical - 1.0
```

Otherwise they are completely identical.

I'm a bit clueless what happened here, what's the reasoning behind both and which I should continue using.

more information:

```
$> LANGUAGE=en_EN apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 72.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Candidate: 72.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 72.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     59.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Post the output of `apt policy firefox` or `apt-cache policy firefox`.

Comment: @DK-Bose added it to the question

Comment: Both executables point to the same wrapper script, so rest assured you have only a single firefox installation.